# Exclude keys from const for Typescript Record

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following const and type which are generated by openapi :

```
export const MyConst = {
  A: 'a',
  B: 'b',
  C: 'c',
} as const;

export type MyConst=
  (typeof MyConst)[keyof typeof MyConst];
```

I want to create a record using values from `MyConst` as following:

```
const mapper: Record<MyConst, string> = {
    [MyConst.A]: 'Test A',
    [MyConst.B]: 'Test B',
};
```

This will throw an error which is that 'c' is missing in record type, so I need to use Partial to bypass this error:

```
const mapperWithPartial: Partial<Record<MyConst, string>> = {
    [MyConst.A]: 'Test A',
    [MyConst.B]: 'Test B',
};
```

But this will make all the keys as optional, I want the keys 'a' and 'b' to be required but this record type cannot have the 'c' key, which mean to exclude it, but for some reason Omit never works in this case.

Here is the TS playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwHgDg9gTgLsAxlAdgZwQWQJ4GFUbAC8wA3gFDBXUCCAXMAOQCGjANJdVQEIOMBG7Tl1x9EQrgF9gzNEgJwA3MOArw0eMDjYIIYDnzo4RFVQAU23VABm+vAoCUAbQDWIbDa06QngwoC6yuTkAPQhWgAWAJZycBEwUADuoDAJMEziwDHAALYxaFEoAOZZKF665MhGucwQujAMAEogyDAAJgA8fkZswBgwhUUAfMRkKk7dGAB0NP58ACoghDQS1BP2RlPcc0yLhNxCkkFhwACqBcXAEMzwUcwANsAW0XKJUfePOcxuMh92hoQAG4PACuSxkcigEDgUVQD16cT0wPuYLkaAiUBB9zawH4ehgIAAjiCogSceoWghGOIHJUFDU6iAYAB1KJxAAKNxhDwYnNuDw6zVanUmcF6-UGQxGJAoXHWALgMx2jD2CBWHDloq2ytVwAOHCOQA

Comment: "record type cannot have the 'c' key," Typescript is structurally typed you can't guarantee at compile time that an object *can't* have a particular key. You can only say "it must have *at least* these keys". Also that `MyConst` type looks wrong: it only captures the *values* from the const object with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youn can use [TypeScript's built-in utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) `Extract` (or its inverse, `Exclude`) to filter a union down to only some of its members. For example:

```js
 export const MyConst = {
      A: 'a',
      B: 'b',
      C: 'c',
    } as const;
    
    export type MyConst=
      (typeof MyConst)[keyof typeof MyConst];


// No error
const mapper: Record<Extract<MyConst, typeof MyConst.A | typeof MyConst.B>, string> = {
    [MyConst.A]: 'Test A',
    [MyConst.B]: 'Test B',
};


// No error
const mapper2: Record<Exclude<MyConst, typeof MyConst.C>, string> = {
    [MyConst.A]: 'Test A',
    [MyConst.B]: 'Test B',
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQUwHgDg9gTgLsAxlAdgZwQWQJ4GFUbAC8wA3gFDBXUCCAXMAOQCGjANJdVQEIOMBG7Tl1x9EQrgF9gzNEgJwA3MOArw0eMDjYIIYDnzo4RFVQAU23VABm+vAoCUAbQDWIbDa06QngwoC6yuTkAPQhwAByUKAwMLDkyEbAALbMELowDABKIMgwACYAPACiYHAwzIhwhX5GbF5WtrUYAHQ0wAA+DT5N9kYt3AB89RgwAJYoAOaDxGQqTs1wbf58ACoghDQS1At9rdwrTOuE3EKSQaHhUTFxMAkKKWkZAEzZubBFpYgANgCu+SAans4PVLD07IZWrhhsBRhNprMKFxdpCljRDoxjggthxkYsBhiscBThxzkA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a life saver <3